# Product of two group morphisms not a group morphism

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory

In Mac Lane's Categories for the Working Mathematician, page 110, second edition, he states that, in the category of groups $Grp$, $F_n$ being groups and $x_n, y_n$ being two cones on these groups (thus a family of group morphisms from X (resp. Y) to $F_n$), these cones form a group by multiplication $x_n y_n$.

As I understand it, it just seems false. Let be two group homomorphisms $g, f$, there is no reason why $x \mapsto g(x) f(x)$ should also be a group morphism, as we cannot conclude whether $g(x)f(x)g(x)^{-1}f(x)^{-1} = e$.

So I probably missed something... I could use a hint!

Edit: as hinted in the comments, it is probably that Mac Lane was reasoning from inside Sets category, instead of Grp. But in this case it looks like it defeats the purpose of the example, as it comes just after a theorem stating that Sets has all small limits, and it would have been a good occasion to show how it works elsewhere than in Sets.

Comment: MacLane writes "...the set L of all cones (all matching
strings x)...". So, he seems to mean cones in the category of sets, not groups.

Comment: Ok, thank you. In this case, this is what lost me. I still don't see the point to be inside Sets, as we already know that Sets have all small limits. It would have been of much value to construct the limit in Grp, which would have been an example of how to do it without the use of the one-point set.

Comment: "There's no reason why $x\mapsto g(x)f(x)$ should be a group homomorphism": you should easily find examples to confirm this expectation.

Comment: @YCor Yes indeed, if the source group is $(R,+)$, if the destination group is the direct isometries of the $R^2$ plane, $E^+(2)$, then if we take $f(1)=rot([0,0],\pi/2)$ and $g(1)=trans(1*e_x)$, we get $g(1)f(1)g(1)^{-1}f(1)^{-1}\neq id$

Comment: And I mixed up because the composition is the reverse of the writing order, but the idea is there: in this case $f(1)^{-1}g(1)^{-1}f(1)g(1) = trans(\sqrt{2}*e_x+\sqrt{2}*e_y) \circ rot([0,0], \pi/4)$

Comment: The *cones* are in $\rm Set$, but the set *of* cones, under pointwise multiplication is the limit in $\rm Grp$.  In fancier language, he's saying that limits in $\rm Grp$ are created in $\rm Set$.

Comment: @MikeShulman Thank you so much, this is the answer I was looking for! Please make it an official one so that I can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

The *cones* are in $\mathrm{Set}$, but the set of *cones*, under pointwise multiplication is the limit in $\mathrm{Grp}$. In fancier language, MacLane's saying that limits in $\mathrm{Grp}$ are created in $\mathrm{Set}$.